# android dynamic asset delivery

Tags: android, assets, android-assets, android-module

I would like to add dynamic asset delivery feature in my app.I need 3 different asset pack to be added . I read the google documentation on this topic but didn't understand anything.Also there no tutorial on youtube .

1. Need step by step procedure.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm puzzling through use of the [FakeSplitInstallManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407887/how-do-i-test-play-store-asset-delivery-with-local-testing-and-bundletool) to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Please explain what you don't understand, I think the official document is detailed enough.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/changcsw/PADSameple-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/padsample/MainActivity.java

this sample was very helpful for me + [official documentation 1](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery/build-native-java) [official documentation 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java).